# PHP JSON Array: Illegal string offset 'first_name'

Tags: php, json

The JSON that's printed out is similar to:

```
{
    "c_id": {
        "value": 66
    },
    "first_name": {
        "value": "Joe"
    },
    ...
```

This comes from the code below

```
    $profile = json_encode($this->session->getProfile(), true);
    echo $profile;
    echo $profile['first_name']['value'];
```

However, I get the errors:

```
 Illegal string offset 'first_name'
 Illegal string offset 'value'
```

Any ideas? I can't see what I'm doing obviously wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `$profile` is no longer `array` but `string`

Comment: json_encode returns a string

Comment: If this `$this->session->getProfile()` is supposed to return a JSON String use `json_decode($this->session->getProfile())`

Answer (score -1):

You must decode your JSON data if you want to access the array:

```
$profile = json_decode($this->session->getProfile(), true);
```

Comment: That could be true if `$this->session->getProfile()` contained a json string. But obviously it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what your second parameter "true" in json_encode is supposed to do?

Answer (score -1):

I m not sure what you want to do but once you have

`$profile = json_decode($this->session->getProfile(), true);`

then the responce you are getting may be a string and you need an object  or vice versa